# Concrete, intuitive category to study basic categorical concepts

Tags: category-theory

I'm a programmer trying to get acquainted with basic category theoretic concepts but I prefer to learn via some concrete, intuitive starting place and then abstract out from there. I taught myself basic algebra (groups, rings, fields, etc) by learning about topological data analysis to motivate my study. All the treatments of category theory seem to teach it terms of abstract categories but as a non-mathematician I find it difficult to stay motivated unless I can inuitively follow why it's useful. I was considering the category of combinatorial games as a reasonable starting place to learn since it's the study of intuitive little two player games. I was wondering if there are any other suitably intuitive categories where basic categoric notions can be ascertained?

Comment: You might be interested in the "category" [Hask](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask), of Haskell (programming language) datatypes and functions between them.  It's not a category, but it's "close" enough to one that it's probably a good example to keep in mind.

Comment: Categories of modules, maybe? Note Object Oriented Programming uses concepts very close to Category theory.

Comment: Did you consult any of several books or online sources devoted to introducing category theory for programmers?

Comment: Most books on categories give plenty of examples of concrete categories. That said, the obvious choice would be Sets.

Comment: @Bernard in what sense does OOP use CT?

Comment: It doesn't use strictly speaking but uses similar ideas (the fact that objects contain procedures, for instance). It has a very strong tast of ‘abstract nonsense’. Also, the most powerful systems of computer algebra use Object Oriented Programming (Axiom is one of these).

Comment: @Bernard For me the two don't have the same taste at all… I find that category theory is very well organized while it is hard for me to see the unity of OOP. But when I was trying to understand OOP I found some writings that looked interesting like the book/collection of papers *Theoretical Aspects of Object Oriented Programming (Types, Semantics and Language Design)* (it looked like category theory was used in it but I was not sure).

Comment: How about the topos of graphs, as elaborated in [this note](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306394)?